# Should your title be "Running R script from Command Line Can't Find Packages

Tags: r, rstudio

I am troubleshooting an issue that I am running into on a new instance of RStudio on a virtual machine.  If I run an R script expFit.R in RStudio, it has no problem finding the needed packages (in this case RODBC and minpack.lm) but if I try to run from the command line

```
c:\"Program Files"\R\R-3.4.1\bin\x64\Rscript.exe e:\expFit.R
```

I get the error 'minpack.lm' is not a valid installed package.  If I move RODBC to be the first package to load, then it errors on that.

The reason that I am running from command line is that in the real application I am running it from a command line stored procedure in SQL.  It doesn't work either way (stored procedure or straight command line).  I made sure that the path to the packages is a Path variable.

This works on 2 of my other servers, the only difference being that RStudio is installed so that all users can use it on the server that is getting the error, while the other servers have it installed only in my account.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Should your title be "Running R script from Command Line Can't Find Packages"?

Comment: Compare the output from running `.libPaths()` from Rscript and Rstudio and compare the results. Sounds like you have different sets of libraries where you have packages installed. And be careful, R isn't the same as Rstudio or Rscript. If you aren't using the graphical user interface, then you're not really using Rstudio at all.

Comment: Thanks Imo, I changed the title I will look at package locations.  Thanks for the input!